# Redefinition of 'ClassName' as different kind of symbol in generated header

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, forward-declaration, bridging-header

I created a Swift enum as an Int (so it will work with Objective-c).

When I build the project, everything is fine. However, as soon as I try to import the class in a .h file (using a forward declaration @ClassName), the generated header file errors out with `Redefinition of 'ClassName' as a different kind of symbol`

Looking in the generated .h file I can see it generated the new type like so:

```
typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, ClassName, closed) {
  type1 = 1,
  type2 = 2,
};
```

It underlines the ClassName saying it's been re-declared. However, it exists nowhere else in the header file (doing a search and it comes up only once) and it's only declared once in a swift file.

Any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are not classes in Objective-C, so you need to use `typedef` instead of forward declaration in your `.h` file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ClassName);
```

and then in `.m` file, you need to import `Module-Swift.h` file.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you this totally worked! I was stuck for a quite a while. Much appreciated.